# How to create model instances from command line (terminal)

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

I thought this would have been a previously asked question, so maybe I'm not phrasing it right.

I tried:

```
manage.py python3.6 dbshell
```

and then:

```
 obj= Person.objects.create('Justin')
```

but this did not work. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You should use *named* parameters, so something like `Person.objects.create(name='Justin')`, how else is Django supposed to know what field `'Justin'` maps to?

Comment: I thought if the parameter names weren't supplied it saves in the order listed in the model?

Comment: There is no order of attributes. The attributes are passed in a dictionary format, so the order is lost. It would also be horrible unstable, since by constructing a new field, then all the constructors should be updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dbshell` command runs the command-line client for the database, so you'd have to use SQL to create a row in your database using that. What you actually want is the `shell` command. It opens a Python interpreter with Django configured, so you can work with ORM there.

Answer (score 8):

You are on the right track, but when you create model instances, you should use *named* parameters for the fields, so for example:

```
obj = Person.objects.create(name='Justin')
```

(given of course a `Person` has a `name` field)

This is logical since a model can have several fields, and there is no "inherent" order.

Using *positional* parameters would be very risky, since a simply "reshuffle" of the fields would result in model object constructions going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```py
obj= Person.objects.create(name='Justin')
```